# `dpkg-query` and virtual packages: how to read or interpret `${Provides}`?

Tags: dpkg, dependencies, deb

#### Background

During my periodic auditing of installed packages, I encountered an error. For this auditing, an application generates a graph of installed packages, using `dpkg-query`. During this process, it checks in the while, all dependencies are indeed satisfied, as this would otherwise mean either something is wrong in the system or something is wrong with the application generating the graph. It happened today the application stopped on an error, telling it found a package with an unsatisfied dependency to `python:any`. However, the depending package is fine. I checked `python:any` is a virtual package provided by the package `python`. Synaptic says `python` provides `python:any`, but my application don't receive this information from `dpkg-query`.

Here is a test you may execute from the command line, which show the issue (assuming Ubuntu 14.04):

```
$ dpkg-query --showformat='${Package}\n${Provides}\n' --show python3
> python3
> python3-profiler
# Note `python3:any` does not appear
```

About the same package, Synaptic says it provides `python3:any` and `python3-profiler`. The former is missing from the informations returned by `dpkg-query`.

When appearing as a dependency, it's fine:

```
$ dpkg-query --showformat='${Package}\n${Depends}\n' --show apturl-common
# Note the second item in the format is now `Depends`
> apturl-common
> python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~), python3-apt, python3-update-manager
```

#### Question

Is this a bug in `dpkg-query`? Or is this me erroneously expecting it to tell about all virtual packages while I may be supposed to infer this kind of virtual packages “myself”? Are they some rules I don't know about what is returned in `${Provides}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)` is not a virtual package, it's a substitution string created by the `${python3:Depends}` pattern and filled by `dh_python3` when called from `dh_gencontrol` when the package was built. Take a look at the `debian/control` file of the `apturl` source package:

```
Package: apturl-common
Architecture: any
Depends: ${python3:Depends},
 ${shlibs:Depends},
 ${misc:Depends},
 python3-apt,
 python3-update-manager
Replaces: apturl (<< 0.3.6ubuntu2)
Description: install packages using the apt protocol - common data
 AptUrl is a simple graphical application that takes an URL (which follows the
 apt-protocol) as a command line option, parses it and carries out the
 operations that the URL describes (that is, it asks the user if he wants the
 indicated packages to be installed and if the answer is positive does so for
 him).
```

Now why `python3:any`? Let's quote the debian policy:

> Specifying only any indicates that the source package isn't dependent
>   on any particular architecture and should compile fine on any one. The
>   produced binary package(s) will be specific to whatever the current
>   build architecture is.

And this is exactly the case for the `python3` binary package:

```
Package: python3
Architecture: any
Multi-Arch: allowed
Pre-Depends: python3-minimal (= ${binary:Version})
Depends: python3.4 (>= 3.4.3-1), libpython3-stdlib (= ${binary:Version}), ${misc:Depends}, dh-python
Suggests: python3-doc (>= ${binary:Version}), python3-tk (>= 3.4.3-1) , python3-venv (>= ${binary:Version})
Replaces: python3-minimal (<< 3.1.2-2)
Provides: python3-profiler
Description: interactive high-level object-oriented language (default python3 version)
 Python, the high-level, interactive object oriented language,
 includes an extensive class library with lots of goodies for
 network programming, system administration, sounds and graphics.
 .
 This package is a dependency package, which depends on Debian's default
 Python 3 version (currently v3.4).
```

Sources:

- https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-controlfields.html#s-f-Architecture
- https://alioth.debian.org/scm/loggerhead/pkg-python/python3-defaults-debian/view/head:/debian/control#L17

Comment: “ is not a virtual package”: indeed, I just came to the same conclusion, just by a different way (see the answer I posted to my own question at the same time you did).

Comment: @Hibou57: Exactly, we posted our  answers almost simultaneously. I agree that Synaptic Provides tab can be confusing.

Comment: Unlike in your example with `python3`, for me and for the package `python`, the file `/var/lib/dpkg/available` says `Architecture: i386`, so `any` is not always to match `any` exactly (just wanted to make it clearer for people who will read your answer).

Comment: @Hibou57: `any` is only visible in the original `debian/control` file (see my second link). Once a binary is built you'll get the one for your arch in `/var/lib/dpkg/available`, hence the `Architecture: i386`.

Answer (score 0):

I feel to guess an anwser, still feel free to add your own anwser.

I've learned there is a `/var/lib/dpkg/available` database, as raw‑text. I checked for `python3` (to go on with the same example as in the question) it says `Provides: python3-profiler`: there is no `python3:any`.

So may be the anwser is: there is not always a direct match between a requirements returned by `dpkg-query` and a package provided as returned by `dpkg-query` too, and probably Synaptic infers a “fake” virtual package, and `python3:any` is not really a virtual package (I would say Synaptic is misleading here).

Most probably there is nothing with de provided packages, and it's me who is erroneously reading `:xyz` at the end of a package dependencies as part of the packag name, while it's not.